# In which status the `Internal error!` invoked?

Tags: bash, getopt

I have read some code on bash's getopt ,let me simplify what i have seen hrere.
[bash sample on getopt containing  Internal error!](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/shell/gsh13-CommandParameters/ar01s02.html)

```
docase(){
TEMP=`getopt -o ab: -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$TEMP"
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) echo "Option a" ; shift ;;
        -b) echo "Option b, argument \`$2'" ; shift 2 ;;
        --) shift ; break ;;
        *) echo "Internal error!" ;;
    esac
done
}
```

I have tried many status to invoke `Internal error!` with `docase g` ,`docase -g`,`docase --g`,never happened.

In which status the `Internal error!` invoked for the above code ?
Maybe it is better to delete `*) echo "Internal error!" ;;`?

Comment: In case getopt implementation is invalid. There are many systems, and such implementations exist. Side note: I always wonder, why people post images, it is just simpler to post text then images.... With images you need use a snippet tool or a paint, paste copy paste, with text on linux you just highlight and use middle mouse button...

Comment: Delete the image.

Comment: This is **not** "bash's getopt", `bash` has a built-in called `getopts` (trailing `s`).  You are using an external program called `getopt` which is nothing to do with `bash`.  Why are you using `getopt` instead of `getopts`?

Comment: The `eval` sets `$1` to `--`.  This means it goes into the `--` test and the `shift` removes `$1` then breaks out of the loop, so "Internal error" will not be hit.
Using `eval` is generally considered to be a security risk, particularly when dealing with user input like parameters.

It is hard to see what you are trying to achieve, can you describe the purpose of this function?

Comment: Which platform are you running on?

Comment: bash sample on getopt containing Internal error!

Comment: http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/shell/gsh13-CommandParameters/ar01s02.html

Comment: I am on debian9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docase(){
TEMP=`getopt -o ab: -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$TEMP"
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) echo "Option a" ; shift ;;
        -b) echo "Option b, argument \`$2'" ; shift 2 ;;
        --) shift ;;
        *) echo "Internal error!" ;;
    esac
done
}
```

To delete break in `--) shift ; break ;;` invoke infinite `Internal error!`.

```
docase(){
TEMP=`getopt -o ab: -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$TEMP"
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) echo "Option a" ; shift ;;
        -b) echo "Option b, argument \`$2'" ; shift 2 ;;
        --) shift ;;
        *) echo "Internal error!" ;break;;
    esac
done
}
```

To add a break in `*) echo "Internal error!"` invoke `Internal error!` only once.