# Why `$OPTIND` can't exist in a function containing getopt?

Tags: bash, getopt

Save the following code as `testme.sh`.

```
OPTS=$(getopt -o a:b:c -- "$@")
eval set -- "$OPTS"
while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -a  )                 
            echo  "i am in a",$OPTIND
            shift 2;;
        -b  ) 
            echo  "i am in b",$OPTIND
            shift 2;;
        -c ) 
            echo  "i am in c",$OPTIND
            shift;;
        -- ) 
            shift;; 
        *)
            break;;
    esac
done
```

Run it with  `bash  /tmp/testme.sh  -a a1 -b b1 -c`.

```
i am in a,1
i am in b,1
i am in c,1
```

Now wrap all content in testme.sh as a function.

```
testme(){
OPTS=$(getopt -o a:b:c -- "$@")
eval set -- "$OPTS"
while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -a  )                 
            echo  "i am in a",$OPTIND
            shift 2;;
        -b  ) 
            echo  "i am in b",$OPTIND
            shift 2;;
        -c ) 
            echo  "i am in c",$OPTIND
            shift;;
        -- ) 
            shift;; 
        *)
            break;;
    esac
done
}
```

Run it with `testme  -a  a1 -b b1 -c`.

```
i am in a,
i am in b,
i am in c,
```

There are 2 issues confused me.

1.Why all `$OPTIND`s value is 1 when to run  `bash  /tmp/testme.sh  -a a1 -b b1 -c` ?

2.Why no `$OPTIND`s value at all  when to run  `testme  -a a1 -b b1 -c` ?

Comment: `$OPTIND` is a set by the `getopts` built-in, not the `getopt` external command.

Comment: Please try it on ubuntu or debian,`bash  /tmp/testme.sh  -a a1 -b b1 -c` get  1 as `$OPTIND`'s value.

Comment: `OPTIND` is initialized to `1` when a script starts. Nothing in your code changes it, that's why it prints `1` every time.

Comment: You must have emptied `OPTIND` before running the `testme` function. When I try it, I see the value of `OPTIND` just like in the script.

Comment: You are still confusing the external program `getopt` with the `bash` built-in `getopts`.  See my comments to your previous question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742613/in-which-status-the-internal-error-invoked

Comment: getopt is more powerful than getopts,i like getopt more than getopts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getopt` is an external command and runs in a subprocess, so it can't modify the original shell's variables. Because of this, it can't set variables like `OPTIND` and `OPTARG`, the way the built-in command `getopts` does. It simply outputs a modified version of the argument list, which can be assigned to positional parameters with `set`.

So when you use `getopt` rather than `getopts`, `$OPTIND` is not updated. It's initialized to `1` when a shell script starts. Since your `testme.sh` script never does anything that updates the variable, you get `1` every time through the loop.

When I try your `testme` function, I also see `1` every time. If you're not seeing this, you must have reassigned `OPTIND` before running the function. Try:

```
OPTIND=123
testme -a a1 -b b1 -c
```

and you should see

```
i am in a,123
i am in b,123
i am in c,123
```